# jQuery slideshows for ecommerce application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am working on ecommerce application. I am searching for some cool jquery image gallery slideshow with text something like ecplaza.net. I tried to copy it from there, but it was'nt working at my end, even after using all js and css files. I search various sites but have'nt came accross any similar Sliders. Please guys help me out.

Comment: -1 It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want help trying to get the CSS /JS you have taken from the given site to work? Or do you want us to recommend a publicly licensed JQuery Gallery? Or do you want us to explain how the JQuery galleries work in regards to CSS, HTML & JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen similar sliders like that, you simply need to keep abreast of the latest tutorials for JQuery Sliders, find the style like the one you want and adapt it to suit your needs.